Reconnect api getting called many times
we have a webchat that is built using React using microsoft directline framework, after building the bot on react, we uploaded the files into azure storage and giving the client the storage link to open using a script tag in their website or where ever they are using the webchat.
The issue here is once its been loaded into clients website, after a day, the reconnect api is getting called too many times and consuming all the browsers memory.
Looking for any answers or suggestions if anyone else faced this kind of trouble
